# Conditionally fill a column downwards based on the presence/absence of information in another column

Tags: r, conditional-statements, fill

I am trying to fill a large file containing taxonomic information so that each row contains relevant data. At present, the file is structured, thus, from infraclass through to subspecies:

| Family | Genus | Species |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F1 | NA | NA |
| NA | G1 | NA |
| NA | NA | S1 |
| NA | NA | S2 |
| NA | G2 | NA |
| NA | NA | S1 |
| NA | NA | S2 |

Here, for example, I would like to fill Genus downwards when there are data in Species, likewise for Family, and then remove the redundant rows. The end result should be something like this:

| Family | Genus | Species |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F1 | G1 | S2 |
| F1 | G1 | S2 |
| F1 | G2 | S1 |
| F1 | G2 | S2 |

I've included example data, below:

```
df <- data.frame(
family = c("Rheaidae",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
genus = c(NA,"Rhea",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
species = c(NA,NA,"americana",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,"pennata",NA,NA,NA),
subspecies = c(NA,NA,NA,"americana","intermedia","nobilis","araneipes","albescens",NA,"garleppi","tarapacensis","pennata")
)
```

I've tried several different ways of combining mutate, ifelse, loops, etc. but I'm not getting anywhere. I've provided one example, below, which didn't work but was my most successful attempt, thus far.

```
df %>%
  mutate(g = ifelse(is.na(subspecies), "NA", 
            zoo::na.locf(species, na.rm = F)))
```

| family | genus | species | subspecies | g |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rheaidae | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| NA | Rhea | NA | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | americana | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | NA | americana | americana |
| NA | NA | NA | intermedia | americana |
| NA | NA | NA | nobilis | americana |
| NA | NA | NA | araneipes | americana |
| NA | NA | NA | albescens | americana |
| NA | NA | pennata | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | NA | garleppi | pennata |
| NA | NA | NA | tarapacensis | pennata |
| NA | NA | NA | pennata | pennata |

EDIT
@benson23 suggested using

```
df %>% fill(everything(), .direction = "downup") %>% distinct_all()
```

I'd come across something like this previously, but even though it does a good job of filling cells, it leaves me with erroneous rows. I've given an example, below:

| family | common | genus | species | subspecies |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Struthionidae | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| NA | Ostriches | NA | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | Struthio | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | NA | camelus | NA |
| NA | NA | NA | NA | australis |
| NA | NA | NA | molybdophanes | NA |
| Rheaidae | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| NA | Rheas | NA | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | Rhea | NA | NA |
| NA | NA | NA | americana | NA |
| NA | NA | NA | NA | americana |
| NA | NA | NA | NA | intermedia |

Becomes:

| family | common | genus | species | subspecies |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Struthionidae | Ostriches | Struthio | camelus | australis |
| Struthionidae | Ostriches | Struthio | camelus | australis |
| Struthionidae | Ostriches | Struthio | camelus | australis |
| Struthionidae | Ostriches | Struthio | camelus | australis |
| Struthionidae | Ostriches | Struthio | camelus | australis |
| Struthionidae | Ostriches | Struthio | molybdophanes | australis |
| Rheaidae | Ostriches | Struthio | molybdophanes | australis |
| Rheaidae | Rheas | Struthio | molybdophanes | australis |
| Rheaidae | Rheas | Rhea | molybdophanes | australis |
| Rheaidae | Rheas | Rhea | americana | australis |
| Rheaidae | Rheas | Rhea | americana | americana |
| Rheaidae | Rheas | Rhea | americana | intermedia |

Rather than:

| family | common | genus | species | subspecies |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Struthionidae | Ostriches | Struthio | camelus | australis |
| Struthionidae | Ostriches | Struthio | molybdophanes | NA |
| Rheaidae | Rheas | Rhea | americana | americana |
| Rheaidae | Rheas | Rhea | americana | intermedia |

In short, the data run-on and there's no clear way to remove the erroneous rows.

Comment: Have you tried the `tidyr::fill()` function? Does `df %>% fill(everything(), .direction = "downup") %>% distinct_all()` give you what you want?

Comment: Sort of. I'd done something similar, previously but the problem is that I then end up with inaccurate rows. I'll edit the post to explain, with a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df %>%
   fill(family)%>%
   group_by(family)%>%
   fill(common:species, .direction = 'downup')%>%
   group_by(across(family:species))%>%
   reframe(across(everything(), ~if(all(is.na(.x)))NA else na.omit(.x)))

# A tibble: 4 × 5
  family        common    genus    species       subspecies
  <chr>         <chr>     <chr>    <chr>         <chr>     
1 Rheaidae      Rheas     Rhea     americana     americana 
2 Rheaidae      Rheas     Rhea     americana     intermedia
3 Struthionidae Ostriches Struthio camelus       australis 
4 Struthionidae Ostriches Struthio molybdophanes NA
```

Comment: This very nearly gets there. However, 'molydophanes' should not be associated with a subspecies name; it should retain the NA. Applying the code to the original example also results in the creation of _Rhea pennata albescens_, which is not a valid species (the first of that species should be _pennata garleppi_).

Comment: @ar.caravaggi and how do you determine that? eg how do you determine that  a certain genus is connected to a certain species for example?

Comment: @ar.caravaggi IT seems you mean that while family, genus and species are running, the rest are fixed. Is that the case?

Comment: Genus and species will be linked, as per your solution. Not all species have associated subspecies, however. The species molybdophanes is an example, here. I do appreciate the nature of the issue, in terms of logically filling data. How does one code so that the result respects a species with no associated subspecies but fills all others?

Comment: Exactly so. Subspecies should be fixed.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much. I'm going to have fun learning to understand the ins-and-outs of that solution.